# Reusing XSLT for different elements (loop?)

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Thanks to a previous post I can now convert

```
<root>
<parent>
<Jack>value1</Jack>
<Jane>value2</Jane>
<spArchie>value3</spArchie>
<spKate>value4</spKate>
</parent>
</root>
```

to

```
<root>
<parent>
<Jack>value1</Jack>
<Jane>value2</Jane>
<childlist>
<value name="spArchie">value3</value>
<value name="spKate">value4</value>
</childlist>
</parent>
</root>
```

using the following XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="childlist[normalize-space(spArchie) or normalize-space(spKate)]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::spArchie | self::spKate)]"/>
    <childlist>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="spArchie | spKate" mode="wrap"/>
    </childlist>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="childlist[not('' = (../spArchie|../spKate))]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="spArchie[normalize-space()] | spKate[normalize-space()]" mode="wrap"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="spArchie[normalize-space()] | spKate[normalize-space()]" mode="wrap">
  <value name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </value>
</xsl:template>
```

So far so good, however in the xml document I also have lots of other nodes on the same level as parent that I want to apply the same functionality to but with different element names. I.e I would like to also change

```
 <teacher>
 <Rachel>value1</Rachel>
 <spChristine>value2</spChristine>
 <spPeter>value3</spPeter>
 <Daisy>value4</Daisy>
 </teacher>
```

to

```
<teacher>
<Rachel>value1</Rachel>
<Daisy>value4</Daisy>
<studentlist>
<value name="Christine">value2</value>
<value name="Peter">value3</value>
</studentlist>
</teacher>
```

I could obviously copy the xslt already created using the different values but that idea makes my skin crawl (red faced if anyone was to ever look at it). Is there a way of executing my xslt in a loop passing in the parameters for the nodes I want to search and move. My thoughts so far are

- Collect all nodes on the same level as parent
- Find all child nodes for a parent with the prefix of sp.
- Pass those a parameters to the xslt I already have.

I am looking for feedback and pointers in implementing this solution. Performance is a key issue.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your original stylesheet could be much more simple as well as more generic:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not (starts-with(local-name(), 'sp'))]"/>
        <childlist>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'sp')]" mode="sp"/>
        </childlist>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="sp">
    <value name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </value>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, you can't apply this directly to your new example input, because:

1. the structure is not the same (no parent `root` element);
2. the name `studentlist` must come from somewhere.

---

### Edit:

> however in the xml document I also have lots of other nodes on the
>   same level as parent that I want to apply the same functionality to

I missed this part. If they are in the same document and on the same level, e.g.

**XML**

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <Jack>value1</Jack>
        <Jane>value2</Jane>
        <spArchie>value3</spArchie>
        <spKate>value4</spKate>
    </parent>
    <teacher>
        <Rachel>value1</Rachel>
        <spChristine>value2</spChristine>
        <spPeter>value3</spPeter>
        <Daisy>value4</Daisy>
    </teacher>
</root>
```

then the above styleheet will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <parent>
      <Jack>value1</Jack>
      <Jane>value2</Jane>
      <childlist>
         <value name="spArchie">value3</value>
         <value name="spKate">value4</value>
      </childlist>
   </parent>
   <teacher>
      <Rachel>value1</Rachel>
      <Daisy>value4</Daisy>
      <childlist>
         <value name="spChristine">value2</value>
         <value name="spPeter">value3</value>
      </childlist>
   </teacher>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's brilliant. I knew there had to be a simpler solution to my original idea. You are right that the only problem is the element name of the list. What I could do is take the name of the parent element and append the word list to it so under `<parent>` the list name would be `<parentlist>` and under `<teacher>` the element would be called `<teacherlist>`. Is there a way of incorporating this functionality in your template?

Comment: @RichardWatts But will `parent` and `teacher` always be the only elements under `root`?  Or the only ones that will have children that start with "sp"?

Comment: There are lots of other elements I want to apply this to, which are all on the same level as 'parent' and 'teacher'.

Comment: I need this applied to all the elements on that level except for two. It is expected that the amount of elements will stay the same for some time so keeping a list of elements to apply this to, or even better elements that are exempt from this functionality is possible.

Comment: @RichardWatts So you're asking how to customize the list name for each element? It's possible - though I don't see why you couldn't just use a generic name for all of them. On the same topic: you should probably take this opportunity to convert **all** the elements that hold data in their names - same as you are doing for the children.

Comment: _take this opportunity to convert all the elements_ : I don't disagree but having the xml this way is a specific requirement (I have already asked why!) _I don't see why you couldn't just use a generic name_: I may of been over complicating matters, a generic name of `<list>` will work